# xcode ipad uiwebview refresh white flash

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a website that i load in the UIWebview for my ipad. After 5 minutes i do a refresh, the problem is that when the page refreshes that you see a white flash, is it possible to replace this white flash with a spinning wheel??

The refresh i do with this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *urlString = @"http://pmcuserportal.azurewebsites.net/pmc/index.php";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webDisplayiPad loadRequest:request];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:300 target:self selector:@selector(updateWeb) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(void)updateWeb
{
    [webDisplayiPad reload];
}
```

Comment: Maybe this link would help: http://www.ngo-hung.com/blog/2012/11/30/prevent-uiwebview-white-flashing-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the UIWebView class reference here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

I haven't tried this myself but it sounds like if you use the Boolean property SupressesIncrementalRendering it might help your situation.

There is also a loading property which you can leverage as well. You could try showing a UIActivityIndicator first in your updateWeb method, then do the reload while continually checking the value of the loading property,once the value of loading is equal to NO,you can stopAnimating and hide the UIActivityIndicator.

Again, I have not tried either of these two suggestions but it sounds like they might work, give it a shot.